# How to disable / Enable plugins?

Tags: java, javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox-addon

We are creating a web application. In there, we would like to disable some plugins installed in the user's browser when the user visit out site, such as video downloaders. Is there anyway we can do using PHP, JavaScript, Java, ASP or whatever other technology? If there is, even though we disable it, will the user be able to enable it by browser settings?

I have seen some

Please help.

Comment: While looking at the answers by jm0 and asku, note that there will always be some people who will get around with whatever tricks you  apply. Google got some smart people, money and all the hardware on their team but still they can't stop Youtube video downloaders.

Comment: yes, the immense amount of effort required to encrypt such data in order to obfuscate it is a waste -- an arms race. Video, for example, will always end up as pixels and audio running across the user's hardware. So in the best case scenario where you manage to completely hide the network traffic (I believe Netflix's videos are fragmented and difficult to download because of this) they can still set up a screen/audio recorder. On older PCs this was difficult because the processor would max out but with each passing day its deemed more trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't think there's really any way around this. Basically you would be controlling their browser (an application on their computer). This is a violation of security and privacy to control someone else's computer in this way.

You can have your site attempt to shut down if it detects such actions, but the technical burden is on your shoulders.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that. But you can make your videos harder to download, for example use temporary video urls, or rewriting your urls.